# Unzip a mail attachment

Tags: c#, gzipstream

The following line gives problems

```
content = new StreamReader(new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(a.RawBytes), CompressionMode.Decompress)).ReadToEnd();
```

> InvalidDataException occurred: The magic number in GZip header is not
>   correct. Make sure you are in a GZip stream.

can I not convert the attachment to a byte array or what am I doing wrong?

```
Attachment a = (from x in mail.Attachments.OfType<Attachment>()
   where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Body) || x.RawBytes != null
   select x).FirstOrDefault();

AttachmentName = a.Name;
string AttachmentType = a.Name.Substring(a.Name.Length - 3, 3).ToUpper();

switch (AttachmentType)
{
   case "ZIP":
      content = new StreamReader(new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(a.RawBytes), CompressionMode.Decompress)).ReadToEnd();
      break;
   default:
      content = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(a.RawBytes)).ReadToEnd();
      break;
}
```

Comment: The Gzip header contains a magic number (file format signature) and that seems to be not a Gzip file, that are you try to unzip...

Comment: Did you add any extra byte to the actual byte array while compressing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A GZip file is not the same thing as a Zip file.  You want System.IO.Compression.ZipFile or ZipArchive.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like that's the solution. Unfortunately that leaves me with another problem as the program is in .NET 3.5 and System.IO.Compression.ZipFile is .NET 4.5 only.